# Irreducibility in $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the polynomial $x^2+3$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$?

I am not sure how to even start the problem. I have been looking online trying to find help to teach myself how to do irreducibility and I am not having much luck. Can anyone offer any help as to where I should begin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $F$ is a field, and $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $2$ or $3$ over $F$, then $P(x)$ is irreducible over $F$ if and only if the equation $P(x)=0$ has no roots in $F$.

Comment: So I am correct in thinking that it is reducible because it could be (x+a)(x+b)?

Comment: We ask does the polynomial have a root in $\mathbb{Z}_7$? Try everything, that is, $0$ to $6$. We get that when $x=2$, the object $x^2+3$ is the zero element, so there is a root, the polynomial is not irreducible. It factors as $(x-2)(x-5)$, or equivalently $(x+5)(x+2)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $x^2+3$ is not irreducible then you can write

$$x^2+3=P(x)Q(x)$$
where $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are non-constant. What can the degree of $P,Q$ be? What can $P,Q$ be then?